# How do I change the default sharepoint domain name?

Tags: sharepoint-online, domain

My current sharepoint domain name is in the following format: apple571.sharepoint.com.

In my office 365 admin center, I have already gone to Settings > Domains to change the default domain from apple571.onmicrosoft.com to orange.com. However, my sharepoint domain remains unchanged.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new feature and procedure, follow steps here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/tenant-rename

Answer (score 2):

I know this not the answer you wanted, but SharePoint online does not have any mechanism to change the domain.  Your SharePoint domain will be [tenantname].SharePoint.com, and there's nothing you can do about.  Cnames and other DNS aliasing doesn't work either.  You can obviously set up a redirect from a friendlier domain to your SharePoint.com domain, but that's about the best you can do.

If you want, you be one of thousands to vote for this feature on uservoice: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13217277-enable-renaming-the-spo-tenant-domain

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to change the SharePoint Online domain name for your organization in Office 365.

To use the new domain name, you would need to purchase a new Office 365 subscription and move all email, files, and any other data you want to keep to the new subscription.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-your-sharepoint-domain-name

Answer (score 1):

Well, now you can change domain. The feature comes with limitations, and is in public preview.

I'm gonna try this for the first time shortly. :)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-your-sharepoint-domain-name

Answer (score 0):

The answer is we cannot change the domain name after the subscription... if you want to use new domain name - you need to subscribe one more time with the new domain in Office 365.

As per Microsoft rules are as below :

**You can't rename the onmicrosoft domain after sign-up.** For example, if the initial domain you chose was fourthcoffee.onmicrosoft.com, you can't change it to be fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com. To use a different onmicrosoft.com domain, you'd have to start a new subscription with Office 365.

**You can't rename your team site URL.** Your team site URL is based on your onmicrosoft.com domain name. Unfortunately, because of the way SharePoint Online architecture works, you can't rename the team site.

**You can't remove your onmicrosoft domain.** Office 365 needs to keep it around because it's used behind the scenes for your subscription. But you don't have to use the domain yourself after you've added a custom domain.

More on the above description is below :

[Domains FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/setup/domains-faq?view=o365-worldwide)